# How to pass arguments to openai-gym environments upon init

Tags: openai-gym

Following [this](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/748) (unreadable) forum post, I thought it was fitting to post it up on stack overflow for future generations who search for it.

**How to pass arguments for gym environments on init?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the meantime the support for arguments in `gym.make` has been implemented, so you can pass key word arguments to `make` right after environment name:

```
your_env = gym.make('YourEnv', some_kwarg=your_vars)
```

The `gym` version that I'm running is `0.12.4`.

UPDATE: This is supported from version `0.10.10.`. [Reference](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/0.10.10/gym/envs/registration.py). Thanks [@Wojciech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2003487/wojciech-migda).

Comment: Accepted your answer over my own

Comment: Passing of kwargs was introduces with `gym` `0.10.10`: https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/0.10.10/gym/envs/registration.py

Answer (score 7):

**Method 1 - Use the built in `register` functionality:**

Re-register the environment with a new name

For example:

> 'Blackjack-natural-v0'

Instead of the original

> 'Blackjack-v0'

First you need to import the register function:

```
from gym.envs.registration import register
```

Then you use the register function like this:

```
register( id='Blackjack-natural-v0', entry_point='gym.envs.toy_text:BlackjackEnv', kwargs={'natural': True} )
```

**Method 2 - Add an extra method to your env:**

If you can just call another init method after gym.make, then you can just do:

```
your_env = gym.make("YourEnv")
your_env.env.your_init(your_vars)
```